# outlook express network password pop up

Tags: windows, windows-xp, email, microsoft-outlook, outlook-express

I am using outlook express and for some reason when I open up a saved html email(I think it is?) I get this "network password pop up" with 2 accounts that no longer exist everytime. I looked in outlook express and they do not exist there. Could these be getting passed in from another machine that is creating and saving them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Outlook and Outlook Express were both installed and being used. -_-